# Search document with empty array field, on ElasticSearch

Tags: arrays, database, elasticsearch, isnullorempty

I have a set of **documents** (type *'article'*) and I want to search for the document that have elements/objects into an **array field**

```
{
    "_type": "article",
    "_source": {
        "title": "Article 1",
        "locations": [
            {
                "address": "ES headquarter",
                "city": "Berlin"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want two queries (just one, but with a little variation):

- get all the articles that have locations
- get all the articles that have NO locations

I tried different things but probably I'm too bad with ElasticSearch:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "type": {
            "value": "article"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "missing": {
                "field": "location",
                "existence": true,
                "null_value": true
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

this doesn't work.

- **How would you fix my query?**

but mainly:

- **How would you perform this search for documents with a field that is an empty array?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If `address` is a mandatory field in `location` array you can modify your query:

```
"must_not": {
  "missing": {
    "field": "locations.address"
  }
}
```

AFAIK, in ES you cannot query non-leaf elements (like your `location` field) (see [issue](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/4888)), and in case `object` types ES flattens the nested fields (see [nested type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html), [object type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-object-type.html)). That's why I suggested to query for one of the leaf elements instead. But it requires that one of them is mandatory (which is unfortunately not satisfied in your case).

Anyway I found the solution using the `_source` parameter inside the [source_filtering](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html):

```
"must_not": {
  "script": {
    "script": "_source.locations.size() > 0"
  }
}
```

Note that using `"lang":"groovy"` you should write: `"script": "_source.locations.size > 0"`

Comment: No, it is not a mandatory field; **how else could I solve?**. And **what would be the difference if it was mandatory?**.

Comment: Wow thanks! This seems to be almost the solution I need :)   
              The problems:_________[1)](/a/) I get a **script_lang not supported [groovy]** (solved just removing the *lang* statement); and [2)](/b/) I get a **Error: could not access: size; in class: java.util.ArrayList** and I don't know how to proceed with that :(

Comment: Ok, it might be beyond my actual knowledge of ES, but here is my tips:

Comment: Solved! It was `_source.locations.size() > 0`! Missed the brackets! It works perfectly now :D!
If you update your answer I'll set it as best one ^^

Comment: I use ES 1.3.0 so I cannot use `mvel` as script language by default so I should have turned on dynamic scripting by adding `script.disable_dynamic: false`. After that with `"lang":"mvel"` I received the same error as you. Note that `mvel` is the default script language.

So I guess `mvel` doesn't support the `size` operation and in other hand your version of ES doesn't support `groovy` script.

If you can, you should upgrade your ES.

Comment: Super! Now it's clear: With `mvel` script language we should use `size()`, but with `groovy` we should use `size`.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't tell you I'm working on the version 0.92, and probably Groovy was not even added there!

Answer (score 15):

If you don't want to enable scripting, you can combine the [Exists Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) with a [must_not](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) bool query, e.g:

```
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "must_not":[
        {
          "exists":{
            "field":"tags"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As per the Elasticsearch documentation

> An empty array is treated as a missing field — a field with no values.

Let's suppose you have two documents in the `article-index` index

```json
# First document
{
    "_type": "article",
    "_source": {
        "title": "Article 1",
        "locations": [{"address": "ES headquarter", "city": "Berlin"}]
    }
}
# Second document
{
    "_type": "article",
    "_source": {
        "title": "Article 2",
        "locations": []
    }
}
```

Expected queries would be:

1. Get all the articles that have locations

```json
GET article-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "exists": {
       "field": "locations"
    }
  }
}
```

2. get all the articles that have NO locations

```json
GET article-index/_search
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "locations"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```